# Separating text to individual columns if tag found

Tags: google-sheets

Is there anyway to use excel or googlesheets to extract each `<img src="......."` to a separate column, if I have a column full of individual snipets of HTML such as this?

```
<li class="thumbs is-selected slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide10" style="width: 84px;"> 


<span>
<span>
<img src="/prod-live/static/WFS/Haefele-HDE-Site/-/Haefele/en_DE/images/default/furniture-handle-aluminium-finger-pull-handle_155.01.831_x/02409281_0.jpg" data-fullsrc="/prod-live/static/WFS/Haefele-HDE-Site/-/Haefele/en_DE/images/default/furniture-handle-aluminium-finger-pull-handle_155.01.831_x/02409281_0.jpg" alt=" ">
</span>
</span>
</li><li class="thumbs  slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide11" style="width: 84px;"> 


<span>
<span>
<img src="/prod-live/static/WFS/Haefele-HDE-Site/-/Haefele/en_DE/images/default/furniture-handle-aluminium-finger-pull-handle_155.01.831_x/02557182_0.jpg" data-fullsrc="/prod-live/static/WFS/Haefele-HDE-Site/-/Haefele/en_DE/images/default/furniture-handle-aluminium-finger-pull-handle_155.01.831_x/02557182_0.jpg" alt=" ">
</span>
</span>
</li><li class="thumbs  slick-slide" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide12" style="width: 84px;"> 


<span>
<span>
<img src="/prod-live/static/WFS/Haefele-HDE-Site/-/Haefele/en_DE/images/default/furniture-handle-aluminium-finger-pull-handle_155.01.831_x/02554585_0.jpg" data-fullsrc="/prod-live/static/WFS/Haefele-HDE-Site/-/Haefele/en_DE/images/default/furniture-handle-aluminium-finger-pull-handle_155.01.831_x/02554585_0.jpg" alt=" ">
</span>
</span>
</li><li class="thumbs  slick-slide" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide13" style="width: 84px;"> 


<span>
<span>
<img src="/prod-live/static/WFS/Haefele-HDE-Site/-/Haefele/en_DE/images/default/furniture-handle-aluminium-finger-pull-handle_155.01.831_x/02600108_0.jpg" data-fullsrc="/prod-live/static/WFS/Haefele-HDE-Site/-/Haefele/en_DE/images/default/furniture-handle-aluminium-finger-pull-handle_155.01.831_x/02600108_0.jpg" alt=" ">
</span>
</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Is it all in one cell? Or divided by rows?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V00i3XlEx5Q2Xp0QZevS5o2pdpU2QNNNX5d8bkHtn3U/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a google sheets example. It's x images per cell  which I want to break down into columns for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this formula B2 of the demo sheet

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A3:A, "<img src=", "♥️<img src="), "♥️"),"img src=""(.*?jpg)"), ""))
```

A slight issue will be the that first column will be empty but I am guessing you are more interested in extracting all the images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but I think that this formula in B3 does what you want.

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXTRACT(A3:A,"img src=""(.*?jpg)"))
```

Here is aa sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tAFGvTZwRL6al3ixM0eOEY5v03kUGgWkscVY8lOij2E/edit?usp=sharing

In the future, please make your sample sheet editable by everyone, to make it easier for people to help.  Thanks.

If this doesn't do what you need, please clarify your question.  And if it does do what you need, please select it as a valid answer, to help others.

Comment: Right I made it editable, tried your formula, but it's not doing what I am after. As it is only listing the first img source instead of listing all of them in seperate columns as per my example. Any idea how to do that? Thank you for your help!